# Linking Website form progress data to GIS

Tags: java, gis, arcgis-js-api

We are trying to develop a website for tracking the progress of pipeline and assets. I want to link progress data entered from forms developed in Java to GIS. We will be capturing all the lat and longs of pipeline stretch and lat and log of progress of work.

I need help in developing shapefile dynamically based on the progress and also to view that shape file in my webpage

Comment: Where is your code ?

Answer (score 0):

The javascript API does have functionality for uploading shapefiles form your desktop into the browser, but you will need another tool to create those shapefiles based on the progress.

For uploading the shapefiles, see the example here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/portal_addshapefile.html
There may be more examples available at https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/.

For creating the shapefiles dynamically, you could use ArcMap or ArcPro if you have those, or one of many python libraries to help write shapefiles.  There may even be some Java libraries to help with this as well but I only work on the front end so I cannot help you there.

Answer (score 0):

For something simple in context, the complexity of what kind of workflow to best suite your needs can range depending on these questions (and probably others I'm not thinking of):

1. Do you absolutely need to create a shapefile for this?  Why can't you just push the form to a spatial database (e.g. [PostGIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostGIS)) and then return the XYs of the points or the string of XYs for line features, etc.?
2. Where is the source of the data & what is the format?  Is it a PDF, text on an HTML page, a .csv file downloadable from a page, etc.?  You may need to implement scraping (from a site) or download and update, or your data could be live streaming - these are all different workflows and you need to establish these boundaries before setting up your workflow.
3. If your end game are points, all you need is XYs in a table format to display in GIS software.  If they are lines or polygons, it'd be a little different.  Again - what output type are they and what are you trying to do with it (e.g. import into QGIS)?

Without these answers, it doesn't make sense for anyone to suggest something to you that could be totally impossible for you to execute.  Please answer these and think through your workflow from beginning to end and/or visa versa.

Cheers,
Shawn